# Make: How to escape spaces in $(addprefix)?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
EXTRA_INCLUDE_PATHS = ../dir1/path with spaces/ \
                      ../dir2/other path with spaces/
CPPFLAGS += $(addprefix -I,$(EXTRA_INCLUDE_PATHS))
```

I want to get “`-I../dir1/path with spaces/ […]`”, but I get instead: “`-I../dir/path -Iwith -Ispaces/ […]`”.

How do I espace spaces in `addprefix`? I've tried doing this trick, but it produces same result:

```
space  =
space +=
#produces “-Isome -Ipath”
CPPFLAGS += $(addprefix -I,some$(space)path)
```

Comment: Even assuming you did this the flags wouldn't work when used on the command line unless you escaped the space in the variable or quoted the "words" in the variable so this seems less than useful of a thing to try to do.

Comment: The short answer is, you cannot.  In general, make does not work well with filenames or paths with spaces in them.  It's best to simply avoid them.  In this case you can get what you need by putting the `-I` option directly into the `EXTRA_INCLUDE_PATHS` variable (along with quotes, for the shell).  But there's no way to get what you want from GNU make's functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do it! As @MadScientist points out, you need to eschew all space-containing filenames in a makefile unless you want to be very sad. A space is a list separator (including in lists of targets), and there is just no way around that. Use symbolic links in your file system to avoid them! (*mklink* on windows, or use cygwin *make* which understands cygwin symbolic links).

That said, in the current case (where you are not defining a list of targets, but merely a list of include dirs), you could use a single character to represent a space, only translating it right at the end.

```
EXTRA_INCLUDE_PATHS = ../dir1/path|with|spaces/ ../dir2/other|path|with|spaces/
CPPFLAGS += $(subst |, ,$(patsubst %,-I'%',${EXTRA_INCLUDE_PATHS}))
```

Check the result:

```
$(error [${CPPFLAGS}])
```

gives `Makefile:3: *** [-I'../dir1/path with spaces/' -I'../dir2/other path with spaces/'].  Stop.`. Here, $CPPFLAGS is in *sh* format—the spaces are quoted with `'` so that the compiler sees each `-I` as a single parameter. *make* simply does not have this level of quoting.

Answer (score 2):

If all your include dirs start with the same character sequence, you can exploit this for use with the substitute command:

```
CPPFLAGS += $(subst  ..,-I ..,$(EXTRA_INCLUDE_PATHS))
```

Check the result with:

```
$(info  ${CPPFLAGS})
```

Answer (score 1):

(this is a slightly different (maybe more elegant) version of @bobbogo's answer)

If you escape spaces with a backslash (`\` ), you can replace the escaped space by a pipe symbol (`|`), add the prefix and then undo the replace operation:

```
EXTRA_INCLUDE_PATHS = ../dir1/path\ with\ spaces/ ../dir2/other\ path\ with spaces/
CPPFLAGS += $(subst |,\ ,$(addprefix -I,$(subst \ ,|,${EXTRA_INCLUDE_PATHS})))
```